# Use initialisation list to deal with objects using different initialisation methods?

Tags: c++

My snippet is following, the aim is to initialise class B properly.

```
   class A
    {
    private:
        double params;
    public:
        A(){}
        A( std::vector<double> const& _x ) : x( _x ) 
         {/*..do something ..*/}

       double Somefunction();// function body defined elsewhere

    };

    class B
    {
       public:
       A a1;     // declaration call default constructor?
       A a2;
       B( std::vector<double>& x,std::vector<double>& y )
        : a1(x),a2(f(y))) 
        {}

       const std::vector<double>& f(std::vector<double>& y) const;

    }

    const std::vector<double> &B::f(std::vector<double>& y) const
    {
    /... do sth .../
    }
```

I have two questions:

in class B, does the declaration call the default constructor for A? or it is merely a declaration.

if I got a bunch of A objs in B, a2,a3,a4,a5.... and their initialisation methods "f()" are different but share some common ground, so I would like to initialize them within the constructor function body, is it possible? (otherwise I need to define f2(),f3(),f4(),f5()... )

Comment: Easiest is to set a breakpoint and see if it gets hit. Having said that, you call a1(x) which is not the signature of the default constructor. So you simply add a constructor to A which takes a double vector and then this one will be used... which is what you did. The declaration of the members is not "code" or "instantiation". Your constructors initializer list is.

Comment: The only stunt you cannot pull off without getting "undefined behavior" is if you use the ``this`` pointer of the object under construction from within the initializer list. The value of ``this`` will not change during construction but if you try to use it, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declaration will **not** call default constructor. Member variables are initialized in the constructor. If you are afraid of improper initialization, remove `A`'s default constructor so compiler will point that out for you.
2. Since each member variable needs to be initialized differently, you will have to create separate fN() method for those member variables

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to explain is to look at 2 versions of "virtually" the same thing and discuss the differences.

The way, `class Outer` does it is usually not used because of the extra call to the default constructor. `class Outer2` avoids that extra call.

```
class Member 
{ 
    int x; 
public: 
     Member(int xv)
         :x(xv)
     {} 
     void SetX( int v ) { x = v; }
};
// Init member in function body:
class Outer
{
    Member m;
public:
    Outer( int v ) // "invisibly" calls Member default constructor
        // : m()     <<-- doing that explicitely is considered good style. 
    { // Here, m is already fully constructed.
        m.SetX(v);
    }
};
// Init member with initializer list
class Outer2
{
     Member m;
public:
     Outer2( int v )
          : m(v)   // Calls constructor Member::Member( int )
     { // Again, m is fully constructed from here on

          // Of course it is possible to call m.SetX( 42 ) here.
     }
};
```